# Able to Drag but not Drop: jQuery Plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement the drop and drop feature in my app using a jQuery plugin as described here: http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/ anyhow, I am only able to drag the list objects and not drop them in my project.

Then, I tried to simply .html file that implements just the drag and drop described without all the complexities of my app.

So, here is the code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>



<section id="demos">
    <h1>Demos</h1>
    <style>
        #demos section {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .sortable {
            width: 310px;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .sortable.grid {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .sortable li {
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            background: #F6F6F6;
            color: #1C94C4;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 22px;
        }
        .sortable.grid li {
            line-height: 80px;
            float: left;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .handle {
            cursor: move;
        }
        .sortable.connected {
            width: 200px;
            min-height: 100px;
            float: left;
        }
        li.disabled {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        li.highlight {
            background: #FEE25F;
        }
        li.sortable-placeholder {
            border: 1px dashed #CCC;
            background: none;
        }
    </style>

    <section>
        <h1>Sortable List</h1>
        <ul id="sortable1" class="sortable list">
            <li draggable="true" class style="display: list-item;">Item 1
            <li draggable="true" class style="display: list-item;">Item 2
            <li draggable="true">Item 3
            <li draggable="true">Item 4
            <li draggable="true">Item 5
            <li draggable="true">Item 6
        </ul>
    </section>
</section>
<script src="/html5sortable/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/html5sortable/jquery.sortable.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#sortable1, #sortable2').sortable();
            $('#sortable3').sortable({
                items: ':not(.disabled)'
            });
            $('#sortable-with-handles').sortable({
                handle: '.handle'
            });
            $('#sortable4, #sortable5').sortable({
                connectWith: '.connected'
            });
        });
    </script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But even this is not working. The examples given on the site are working properly, so there has to be something wrong.

I have properly downloaded and included all the files that need to be downloaded/included?

Comment: none of your `li` tags are closed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an additional "/" in the relative address that you have defined. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to close your `li` tags like this:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="sortable list">
    <li draggable="true" class style="display: list-item;">Item 1</li>
    <li draggable="true" class style="display: list-item;">Item 2</li>
    <li draggable="true">Item 3</li>
    <li draggable="true">Item 4</li>
    <li draggable="true">Item 5</li>
    <li draggable="true">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvncN/)

Comment: It's still not working. Yes, I see that it's working in Fiddle.

Comment: Kindly see this follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512312/drag-and-drop-working-in-fiddle-but-not-locally

Comment: Kindly see this follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512312/drag-and-drop-working-in-online-but-not-locally

Ignore the above comment.