# Drag and Drop working in online but not locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Kindly see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvncN/
This **fiddle** implements a simple **Drag and Drop** list and is working fine.

And also when I run the same code using a **Wamp Server** localhost, it is working fine.
But anyhow, when I try to do it locally in my laptop (without **wamp server**), I am not able to do it.

So, here is the code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>



<section id="demos">
    <h1>Demos</h1>
    <style>
        #demos section {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .sortable {
            width: 310px;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .sortable.grid {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .sortable li {
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            background: #F6F6F6;
            color: #1C94C4;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 22px;
        }
        .sortable.grid li {
            line-height: 80px;
            float: left;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .handle {
            cursor: move;
        }
        .sortable.connected {
            width: 200px;
            min-height: 100px;
            float: left;
        }
        li.disabled {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        li.highlight {
            background: #FEE25F;
        }
        li.sortable-placeholder {
            border: 1px dashed #CCC;
            background: none;
        }
    </style>

    <section>
        <h1>Sortable List</h1>
        <ul id="sortable1" class="sortable list">
            <li draggable="true" class style="display: list-item;">Item 1
            <li draggable="true" class style="display: list-item;">Item 2
            <li draggable="true">Item 3
            <li draggable="true">Item 4
            <li draggable="true">Item 5
            <li draggable="true">Item 6
        </ul>
    </section>
</section>
<script src="/html5sortable/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/html5sortable/jquery.sortable.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#sortable1, #sortable2').sortable();
            $('#sortable3').sortable({
                items: ':not(.disabled)'
            });
            $('#sortable-with-handles').sortable({
                handle: '.handle'
            });
            $('#sortable4, #sortable5').sortable({
                connectWith: '.connected'
            });
        });
    </script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And here is the error in the console log:

```
Failed to load resource file:///C:/html5sortable/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
Failed to load resource file:///C:/html5sortable/jquery.sortable.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Why is the code working properly on **Fiddle** and **Wamp Server** but not when opened Seperately as `file:///C:/wamp/www/test.html`

I want it to be able to work completely offline, without **Wamp Server** because I am later going to put all these files into one **Hybrid Android App** which is supposed to be working offline. What so I do to have it work offline?

Comment: The jquery files are in the proper directory? Check your browser console for any such errors.

Comment: Are you missing jQuery UI 1.8.18?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Javascript console? Are the jQuery files loaded when you opening the the page in your browser?

Comment: Include jquery via cdn it will work then

Comment: No the jquery files are not loaded, the errors are shown in the console. Anyhow, it is working fine when run through Wamp Server. But I want it to work locally too. What should I do?

Comment: @ShivamChopra And how do we do that? I am new to jQuery.

Comment: @ShivamChopra Will that make it work completely offline. Will I be able to have it work on my user's device offline?

Comment: In order to work it offline you provide a correct path for your jQuery or jQuery UI. 
As cdn only works for online web apps.

Comment: @ShivamChopra I just goggled for jquery via cdn and it looks like I am already using an old version.

Comment: find correct path for your jQuery and jQuery UI folder. then it will definitely gonna work

Comment: Yeah! actually you are right your version of jQuery and jQuery UI are old but that's not the problem as of right now. Your problem is that you are bot able to get your files on web browser.

Comment: @ShivamChopra Yeah. I just updated the jQuery too. Still no use.

Comment: Your code is not working because WAMP server automatically find out the relative path but as you are not providing the actual path of files when opening separately that may be the problem.

Comment: @ShivamChopra It is working now. Thanks. It's just that I had an extra '/' before the starting of the relative address to load the .js files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an additional "/" in the relative address that you have defined. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related with your laptop but is related with your browser support. Use a developer tools (such as firebug) and trace the error.Then, we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Hey Just checked at my end its working fine at local and online....you just missed the jquery library....

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or by downloading jquery library at locally and place in js folder as shown below:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

all the best...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/` from path you have provided in your code.